# Django Rest Framework "myusers" "This field is required

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am learning DRF and I've now run into a problem that has stalled me for days.  The app is a zumba class application and I'm using DRF to create an API on top of it.  The part I am trying to build right now is the part where a user can add himself to a zumba class(so, he has to be able to update a manytomany field)  What I'd like the API to do when the user register himself to the class(PUT, or PATCH), is to take his username, that we get from the authentication, and add him to "myusers" field.  But since the PUT is empty, the API keeps complaining that "myusers" is required.

Is there a way to tell the API that "myusers" is not required in the PUT request since it is extracted from the authentication token? (If I manually create a PUT request with `"myusers": [{"id": 9}]` in the body, it works but I'd like to avoid adding that client side since the data passed is not even used.)

The serializer(all the reado-only fields are to make sure the user cannot update them):

```
class UserActivityClassesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activitytypename = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='activitytype', slug_field='name', read_only=True)
    activitytype = ActivityTypeSerializer(read_only=True)
    myusers = MyUsersSerializer(many=True) # serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='myusers-detail', read_only=True) 
    uri = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = [
            'uri',
            'id',
            'name',
            'date',
            'activitytype',
            'activitytypename',
            'status',
            'myusers',
        ]
        read_only_fields = [
            'uri',
            'id',
            'name',
            'date',
            'activitytype',
            'activitytypename',
            'status',
        ]


    def get_uri(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return api_reverse("api-activities:classes-detail", kwargs={"id": obj.id}, request=request)
```

The view

```
class ActivityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Activity.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff or self.action == 'create':
            return AdminActivityClassesSerializer
        else:
            return UserActivityClassesSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = self.get_object()
        request = serializer.context['request']
        auth_user = request.user
        qs = instance.myusers.filter(id=auth_user.id)#we verify is the user is already registered, and if yes, we remove him
        if qs:
            print('delete')
            instance.myusers.remove(auth_user)
            return instance
        else:
            result = verify_valid_season_pass(auth_user, instance)
            if result == 1:
                print('add')
                instance.myusers.add(auth_user.id)
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("No valid seasonpass found.")
```

The model that gets updated:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    CLOSE = 0
    OPEN = 1
    ACTIVITY_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (CLOSE, 'Closed'),
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
    ]
    name            = models.CharField('Activity Name', max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    date            = models.DateTimeField('Start Date & Time', blank=False, null=False)
    activitytype    = models.ForeignKey(ActivityType, blank=False, null=False, default=1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    status          = models.IntegerField('Status', choices=ACTIVITY_STATUS_CHOICES, default=OPEN,)  # 1 = open, 0 = closed
    myusers         = models.ManyToManyField("users.User")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`myusers = MyUsersSerializer(many=True, required=False)`

Comment: So simple.   I'm still learning and sometimes the solution is so dang simple. :-/  Thanks!